# PHP Redirect > Blank page

Tags: php, redirect

I ask for your help to make a php redirect.

I made a code from some notes and online it seems to work, however some people are pointing out that they don't work and instead of being redirected to the page, they are presented with a white screen, as if it does not load the page.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$qblog = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (strpos($qblog, '/blog/') !== false || strpos($qblog, '/cart/') !== false || strpos($qblog, '/cartsearch/') !== false)
    $qpath = '../';
else
    $qpath = '';
require_once($qpath . "res/x5engine.php");
$qfolder  = $imSettings['general']['public_folder'];
$qurl     = pathCombine(array(
    $imSettings['general']['url'],
    $qfolder
));
$pa       = Configuration::getPrivateArea();
$dati     = $pa->whoIsLogged();
$username = $dati['username'];
$realname = $dati['realname'];
$datiUser = $pa->getUserByUsername($username);
$email    = $datiUser['email'];
$userpage = $pa->getLandingPage(); //Entry page
/*$avatar   = glob($qpath . $qfolder . "/avatar-" . $username . ".*");
$tsfoto   = 0;*/
if ($username)
  {
    header( "Location:$qpath $userpage"); 
    die;
 }
else
  {
    header( "Location:$qpath imlogin.php"); 
    die;
  }  
?>
```

Am I wrong something?
It works for me, but I don't understand why some users find the blank page.
Online Test Page: https://www.stiac.it/user-area.php

Comment: An URL should not contain spaces.

Comment: So I should put  header("Location:$qpath$userpage");  spaceless!?

Comment: Considering `$qpath` is `../` or the empty string, then yes.

Comment: How come some people only see the blank page and I don't?

Comment: I've no clue ...

Comment: I sincerely thank you for the support